# How do you use a website URL with no obvious extension

Tags: asp.net, facebook, url

I am looking for any reference material for me to read up on, relating to what enables the following scenario where a website has a unique identifer appended to their domain name.

When you go to Facebook and view your profile, the URL in the address bar is something lile;

```
https://www.facebook.com/your_user_name.number
```

There is no obvious file extension, nor is the 'your_user_name.number' being passed as querystring value. I do know that I could create a folder on the web directory which is this name, and then you can direct to that folder and it will autoload the default or index files based on your web server settings. But i am not sure this is happening in this case, as then Facebook would have to create 2 billion + folders?

Browsing to your Photos on Facebook, it the url then looks like;

```
https://www.facebook.com/your_user_name.number/photos
```

I am keen to understand what this type of technical configuration is called. Happy to read up on it myself and learn about it, but I don't even know what it's called to search and read up on.

Any pointers?

Comment: Lookup URL rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is URL rewrite.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

You can basically do whatever you want! No need for extensions or folders at all if you don’t want them anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Dan. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm already testing out some examples now. Cheers mate!